# Comparison method violates its general contract! while sorting Image contours in java

Tags: java, sorting, opencv, compare, contour

I know there might be other similar questions but they still did not resolve my issue. I'm trying to sort Image contours based on their contour area using the following:

```
contours.sort((Object o1, Object o2) -> 
(int) (Imgproc.contourArea((MatOfPoint) o1) - Imgproc.contourArea((MatOfPoint) o2) + 0.5));
```

You see that the sorting comparison is simple (just the difference between the areas) but I still get the mentioned error. I could not figure out why. Maybe because the areas are double and I'm converting the difference to int? Thanks.

Comment: It's probably due to your `+ 0.5`, why do you have that there?

Comment: no. without it is same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to compare [two doubles](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#contourArea(org.opencv.core.Mat)):

```
contours.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(a -> ImgProc.contourArea((MatOfPoint) a));
```

---

The cast is a bit dubious too: unless you're actually trying to sort a list of `Object`, use the element type. Assuming that `contours` is a `List<? extends Mat>`:

```
contours.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(ImgProc::contourArea));
```

---

The specific problem that you've likely got here is with transitivity: if `a == b` and `b == c`, then the contract of the comparator requires  that `a == c` also. (Here, `x == y` means `compare(x, y) == 0`).

But because of the narrowing from double to int, this requirement is violated. Consider `a = 0`, `b = 0.5`, `c = 1`: `int(b - a) == 0`, and `int(c - b) == 0`, so "`a == b`" and "`b == c`".

However, `int(c - a) == 1`, so "`a != c`". Thus, the contract is violated.